# Adding letsencrypt ssl to jenkins server

Tags: ssl, jenkins, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a jenkins server with ipaddress ip.ip.ip.ip:8080.

Currently its running on http and i need to add ssl using certbot here.

Can we add SSL to ip or should i require a subdomain or domain name for this.

Have done a method using nginx reverse proxy

Follows the conf file for a subdomain

```
server {
     listen [::]:80;
     listen 80;

     server_name jenkins.thejus.cloudns.cl;

     return 301 https://jenkins.thejus.cloudns.cl$request_uri;
 }

 server {
     listen [::]:443 ssl;
     listen 443 ssl;

     server_name jenkins.thejus.cloudns.cl;

     ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/jenkins.thejus.cloudns.cl/fullchain.pem;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/jenkins.thejus.cloudns.cl/privkey.pem;

     location / {
         proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
         proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080;
         proxy_read_timeout  90;
         proxy_redirect      http://127.0.0.1:8080 https://jenkins.thejus.cloudns.cl;

         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_request_buffering off;
         add_header 'X-SSH-Endpoint' 'jenkins.thejus.cloudns.cl:50022' always;
     } 
 }
```

I dont need a server name here , rather i need acces to jenkins just using ip.ip.ip.ip:8080

Comment: you cant use a verified SSL provider like letsencrypt for an IP address. However you could generate dummy certs with openssl and use those.

Comment: how to secure jenkins server ip.ip.ip.ip:8080 with ssl then???

Comment: its just as secure, the ssl authority is a way of letting browsers know that a varified person who is allowed to created the cert. The encryption level can be the same or greater. just know that you will have to bypass the browser warning. (this is a fairly common practice for something line an internal jenkins server

Answer (score 0):

You can add SSL directly to Jenkins or put an Nginx in front of it.
In both cases you need a DNS entry pointing toward the server IP and a letsencrypt certificate generated for that DNS entry.

For Nginx, the config file can look like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name build.mydomain.com;
    location /{
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass              "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    ssl on;
    server_name build.mydomain.com;
    ssl_certificate             /etc/ssl/certs/fullchain.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key         /etc/ssl/private/build.mydomain.com.key;
    ssl_trusted_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/build.mydomain.com.cer;
    location /{
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass              "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
    }
}
```

Of course, you need to make sure the three files are copied in the reffered folders:

```
/etc/ssl/certs/fullchain.cer
/etc/ssl/private/build.mydomain.com.key
/etc/ssl/certs/build.mydomain.com.cer
```

I have failed in making redirect working in this scenario.

Comment: I had done this using a domain name , but in my case I only need like ip.ip.ip.ip:8080, while searching in browser to be secured